# How can I include headers from a directory and all its subdirectories in my makefile?

Tags: c++, linux, makefile

My project organization is as follows:

- Makefile
- build

  - objects
  - apps
- include

  - subdirectory (contains *.h)
  - subdirectory (contains *.h)
- src

  - subdirectory (contains *.cpp)
  - subdirectory (contains *.cpp)

In my makefile, to grab all *.h from the subdirectories I currently use:

```
#includes (.h / .hpp)
INC_DIRS := \
$(wildcard include/*/)

INCLUDE = $(foreach d, $(INC_DIRS), -I$d)
```

This *does* work, and I am able to compile fine. However I was wondering if there was a simpler way to include all subdirectories in a single include statement.

The current method I am using does a '-Iinclude/subdirectory' for each subdirectory and it looks really messy and confusing in the terminal.

Comment: Don't do that! You should only do -Isrc -Iinclude and your source code should do #include <foo/bar.h> for include/foo/bar.h

Answer (score 2):

Given your include path approach, this is a good way to specify it in your makefile.

However, it would be better to *not* require all these subdirectories to be in the path, and instead use relative paths inside your code.

```
#include "somedir/thing.h"
#include "somedir2/otherthing.h"
```

and so forth.

This will also then be much easier to port to other build systems if needed.

Comment: Or else #include <foo/bar.h> for include/foo/bar.h